# I am stuck with standing waves mathematical treatment when I am using a complex function

Tags: waves, complex-numbers

$$f=Ae^{i\omega t}\big(e^{-ikz}-e^{ikz}\big) = -2iAe^{i\omega t}\sin(kz)$$

This is the displacement equation I got. As it is complex, I used the real part to represent the nth normal mode of standing wave which is having both position and time dependent term as sine function. At $t=0$ , this gives me zero amplitude at any point $z$. I am following H. J. Pain, The Physics of waves and vibrations book.

Comment: It can be correct! Please notice that the time derivative does not vanish at $t=0$. If this does not help, please clarify what is the difficulty.

Comment: How is this zero at t=0?

Comment: What are you stuck with?

Comment: Hi Tarun. I've replaced the picture of your equation with MathJax; if you need a reference to do this yourself in the future, you can find one [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/473315).

Answer (score 0):

The displacement of the standing wave vanishes for any point $z$ twice every period. There is nothing wrong here